# AutoCompleteBox displayng the suggestions list above the text box

Tags: windows-phone-8, autocomplete, windows-phone, alignment

I'm using a AutoCompleteBox Control from Microsoft Phone Toolkit in a WP8 application.
I positioned the control at the top of the page (bellow the title). However, the suggestions list is displayed above the control (is covering the title of the page and is not good-looking). 
  Is there a possibility to programatically set the AutoCompleteBox to display the Items bellow the control?

Comment: Am having the same problem. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, the only workaround was to replace the control from Microsoft Toolkit with a custom control made by myself. I used a simple text box and a long list selector bellow it in which I was filtering the items every time the text changed in the textbox.

Comment: Also, another problem I discovered about this control is that it was looking differently on dark/light theme (at least on some devices, maybe not all).